# Frequency response of ffmpeg filters

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, filtering, frequency-analysis

I'm using ffmpeg to decode and encode signal. It works perfectly and I added filters. For example, I'm using such a command :

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/dr_click/live.wav -af "anequalizer=c0 f=200 w=100 g=-5 t=0|c1 f=200 w=100 g=-5 t=0, anequalizer=c0 f=1000 w=100 g=3 t=0|c1 f=1000 w=100 g=3 t=0" -acodec pcm_s16be -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

I'm streaming my file, adding 2 filters with 200 Hz and 1000 Hz as central frequency and 100 Hz width and it works.

With such a filter, I know my gain will be -5db at 200Hz. But what is the gain for frequencies at 250 Hz ? Still -5db ? -4.5db ? -3db ? And same question at 350Hz or any other frequency.

What I'm looking for and didn't found is the way to get the frequency response of such a filter for a bandwith from 20Hz to 20kHz. In other words, what I'd like to know for any frequency is : gain = f (frequency) with a given ffmpeg filter

Thank you for your help,

Dr_Click

Answer (score 0):

i'm working on a quite similar issue. Mine is to replace the system wide 15 band graphical LADSPA equalizer (mbeq_1197, controlled by JACK Rack) with an ffmpeg filter. As it is AFAIK impossible to adjust ffmpeg filter parameters during runtime, I have to rely on my already generated JACK EQ settings and need to transfer them to the ffmpeg EQ. Alas, I could not find any two "comparable" EQs: ffmpeg only offers a 18 band "superequalizer". My previous EQ has 15 bands, so I decided to do some interpolations and compare the frequency responses of the old and the new EQ.

Now to answer your question: I'm not an audio engineer, and I'm sure there are more professional ways. But what I found out for now is my current workflow:

1. Generate some white noise. In Linux you can e.g. use sox oder Audacity. In Audacity do *Generate -> Built-in -> Noise... => White noise* (1 min should be enough)
2. Save the file as WAV.
3. Apply your filter to this WAV: `ffmpeg -i whitenoise.wav -af "<your filter>" whitenoise_filtered.wav`
4. Load the filtered file into Audacity and do *Analyze -> Plot Spectrum...*

   The output will be a little scattered because the white noise is not perfect, but this should be negligible.

Good luck!

Flittermice